# How to write a message to Microsoft Teams with Azure ClientApplication Token

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

I try to send a message to Microsoft Teams with the graph api and a non-personal ClientApplication token.

It is currently no problem to get the token from Azure by clientId / secret / tenantId. The token seems to work as well, so I'm able to get e.g. the list of all azur users by rest api. But when I try to send a message to Teams with this token (POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages)), the result is
{
"error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"innerError": {
"date": "...",
"request-id": "..."
}
}
}

The same call works fine with my personal bearer token.

Any idea how to enable the clientapp to post to teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, you are using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token, then use the token to call Microsoft Graph, if so, the `Application permission` is needed.

You got the error because the Microsoft Graph - [Create chatMessage in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) does not support the `Application permission`, it means you could not use the client credential flow in this case.

[image]

---

FAQ:

> The token seems to work as well, so I'm able to get e.g. the list of all azure users by rest api.

To call different APIs via this flow, you need different `Application permission`, this works because your app has the [application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) to call the api - [List users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

> The same call works fine with my personal bearer token.

I suppose you are using another flow to get the token, e.g. [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), [ropc flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). These flows need the `Delegated permission`, which is supported to [create chatMessage in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

[image]